# mac: concatenate contents of text files across many directories; append directory names to corresponding text file contents

Tags: grep, find, sed, awk

In the following directory structure:

directory1
-subdirectoryA
---fileA.txt
-subdirectoryB
---fileB.txt
subdirectoryC
---fileC.txt

I would like to generate a text file containing the following text concatenated:

name of subdirectoryA
-text contained within fileA.txt
name of subdirectoryB
-text contained within fileB.txt
name of subdirectoryC
-text contained within fileC.txt

I was able to use the following commands to get the contents of the text files concatenated, but information I need the directory name to organize the output:

```
find ./prefix_common_to_all_target_directories* -name "*.txt" -exec cat '{}' \; > concatenated_extracted_info.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while read mydir; do
    echo "${mydir}:" >> output.txt
    cat $mydir/*.txt >> output.txt
done < <(find test* -type d )
```

This is looping through all the directories within `directory1` and does exactly what you want. Please note that you have to run this script within `directory1`.

---

Some explanations:

First `find test* -type d` runs which prints every subdirectory's name per line. This output is then fed into `read mydir` running everything within the `while` loop once for each line (`$mydir` is assigned to every line (aka subdirectoy name)).
Then the first line within the loop writes the directory name followed by a colon into `output.txt`, using `>>` which means "append to a file" (if file doesn't exist, it will be created).
The second line within the loop writes the contents of every `*.txt` file within the subdirectory to `output.txt`, again in "append-mode".

---

My test setup (with the above script saved as `createfile.sh`):

```bsh
$ ls *
test1:
fileA.txt

test2:
fileB.txt

test3:
fileC.txt
$ bash createfile.sh
$ cat output.txt 
test1:
file content from dir1
test2:
test content from dir2
test3:
test content from dir3
```

Comment: thank you! this worked perfectly! Now I will figure out why ;)

Comment: @goobergrape I've added an explanation and simplified the code. If my answer helped you I'd appreciate you accepting (the `✓` on the left) it. :)

Comment: Wow that's incredibly helpful and appreciated! Thank you for the explanation. I have checked the accept, thank you also for making me aware of this. Cheers! 